# SELECT FROM WHERE statement not working when a variable is used…

Tags: javascript, sql

I'm using the following code:

```
d2 = "10 Day"
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CourseTable WHERE c_type=".d2."', [], function (tx, results) {
    alert("from jquery value: " + $d2)  
    var d3 = results.rows.item(0).c_days;
});
```

How do I get the WHERE c_type statement to work with a variable?

I've and tried so many combos of characters (e.g. "'.&$%).

When I use c_type='10 Day' it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some flavors of SQL also uses single-quotes for text delimiters and not double-quotes, which is why c_type='10 Day' works but c_type="10 Day" does not.

Comment: @Duston In my case both formats work with value typed in. I want to use a variable assigned the value, i.e. "d2".  I noticed that I did not change the alert var back, it should be "d2" not "$d2". Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer! c_type=?", [d2],

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CourseTable WHERE c_type=?", [d2], function (tx, results) {
```